# Problems with the layout and positioning in CSS

Tags: css, layout

I just started learning HTML and CSS and I have been stuck on the layout of a website in css for a while now. In the first picture you can see how i am trying to make it look and in the second picture you see how it looks right now... 
I tried searching online but I don't seem to grasp the way layout and positioning works in CSS. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong??

[Picture here!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSIQe.jpg)
[2nd picture here!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RoXD7.jpg)
html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Catamaran:100|Pontano+Sans|Ruda:900" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>ALISAN'S OCCASIONS</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">
    </div>
    <div class="home_page">
        <div class="home_left">
            <ul id="social_media">
                <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank"><img src="Facebook1.jpg"></a></li>
                <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/" target="_blank"><img src="Instagram1.jpg"></a></li>
                <li><a href="https://twitter.com/?lang=en" target="_blank"><img src="twitter1.jpg"></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="home_center">

        </div>
        <div class="home_right">

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and this the CSS stylesheet

```
* {

    box-sizing: border-box;
}


body {

    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #8799b7;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    max-height: 735px;

} 


.header {

    display: block;
    background-image: url("header4.jpg");
    height: 500px;
}

.home_page {

    display: block;
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;

}

.home_left {

    display: inline-block;
    height: 235px;
    width: 506px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}


.home_center {

    display: inline-block;
    height: 235px;
    width: 506px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.home_right {

    display: inline-block;
    height: 235px;
    width: 506px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. Just saying it doesn't look right isn't much help. - http://learnlayout.com/

Comment: You are right! I wasn't quite sure how I could explain what is wrong, but I uploaded another picture of how the layout looks now, how that helps ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify your code by using `flexbox`, as long as you don't need to support older browser.

The HTML would be:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Catamaran:100|Pontano+Sans|Ruda:900" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>ALISAN'S OCCASIONS</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">
      header
    </div>
    <div class="home_page">
        <div class="home_left">
           left
        </div>
        <div class="home_center">
center
        </div>
        <div class="home_right">
right
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The CSS:

```
* {

    box-sizing: border-box;
}


body {

    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #8799b7;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    max-height: 735px;

} 


.header {

    display: block;
    background-image: url("header4.jpg");
    height: 500px;
}

.home_page {

    display: flex;
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;

}

.home_page > div {
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.home_left {

    height: 235px;
    width: 506px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}


.home_center {

    height: 235px;
    width: 506px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.home_right {

    height: 235px;
    width: 506px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

And you can see it in action at:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EvqXmg